# Flutter: Multiple Imports Use Same Class Argument

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two imports, one that I wrote as a general theme for my app `FlutterFlowTheme` and one that imports the `Image` library ([here](https://pub.dev/packages/image)). Both use the class `Color`, however, no matter how I rename the imports, I cannot stop getting an error on the Color import being used in both of them. Here is what I have

Theme file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class FlutterFlowTheme {
  static const Color primaryColor = Color(0xFFF05A50);
  static const Color secondaryColor = Color(0xFF58CBD8);
  static const Color tertiaryColor = Color(0xFF1E1E24);
  static const Color greyColor = Colors.grey;
}
```

Then I am doing some image processing in a seperate file with the `Image` library, but I keep getting an error when I try to define the color as `FlutterFlowTheme.secondaryColor`

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as ui;
import '../../flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';

//the error is at the color here
tester = ui.fillFlood(tester, x: 0, y: 0, color: FlutterFlowTheme.secondaryColor);
```

The error is

```
Error: The argument type 'Color/*1*/' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color/*2*/'.
 - 'Color/*1*/' is from 'dart:ui'.
 - 'Color/*2*/' is from 'package:image/src/color/color.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/image-4.0.17/lib/src/color/color.dart').
    tester = ui.fillFlood(tester, x: 0, y: 0, color: FlutterFlowTheme.secondaryColor);
                                                                      ^
```

I have tried the `hide Color` keyword, tried other names for the `Image` package, and nothing has really worked.

Answer (score 1):

You try to use a method **fillFlood()** which last parameter is **package:image/src/color/color.dart** not **dart:ui/color**.

You can't use the **dart:ui/color** class here, to define your color. You have to use **package:image/src/color/color.dart** which name is **ui.Color** in your case.

Pass **ui.Color** class as parameter.

```
class FlutterFlowTheme {
  static ui.Color primaryColor = ui.ColorUint32.rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

tester = ui.fillFlood(tester, x: 0, y: 0, color: FlutterFlowTheme.primaryColor);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Just to make sure I understand the `ColorUnit32` correctly, would `Color(0xFF58CBD8)` then become `ui.ColorUint32.rgba(0x58, 0xCB, 0xD8, 0xFF)`?

Comment: I don't know this library, just picked a constructor from the list, to show what's the problem with the code. Please check the library documentation. I have never used this library.